# android spinner - how to show only text after select item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-spellcheck

I have `Spinner` with custom layout in Android Studio:
user can choose item with custom layout ( Image + text)
I need to view only text on spinner after selected
not full layout

[image: custom layout]

[image]

NOT LIKE THIS:

[image]

---

My custom `Adapter`:

```
public class ColorAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<colorItem> {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList< colorItem>  items;
    public ColorAdapter2(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                         ArrayList< colorItem> objects , LayoutInflater inflater) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.inflater = inflater;
        items = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) {

        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_item, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nameColor);
        label.setText(items.get(position).getName());

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iconColor);

        icon.setImageResource(items.get(position).getImageId());
        return row;
    }
}
```

...and the row layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconColor"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/blue_image"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameColor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

please try manually hide elements by

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {                
        view.findViewById(R.id.viewYouWantToHide).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

and you probably need to restore elements you hide to be visible when  spinner is re-selected with another element or selected nothing

Comment: Thanks . It's work , but I still have a big size( size of the image and text) on spinner after item selected

Comment: Spinner must be like image 2 in my question

Answer (score 0):

Use view provided by event for hidden/make visibility zero for default text or selected text on spinner or static text.

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

On Spinner Item Selected Hide your `Imageview` and set it visible on Nothing Selected

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here

      selectedItemView.findViewById(R.id.iconColor).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

So you can listen to the itemSelectedEvent and then retrieve ImageView from it and then set it's visibility to "GONE".

Here is the example how you are gonna do this.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View view, int position, long id) {
    // your code here
ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.iconColor);
imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}
});
```